# Get all information about a street in OpenStreetMap

Tags: coordinates, openstreetmap, street-address

I've been playing around with API, XAPI and Overpass of OSM. But I can not get some info a need: to get all information nodes of a street.

Here a example:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/5671291

This gives information of a way called "Watts Street" (in NYC), but it's not all the street, just a part of it.

The other part:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/46116390

This happens with some streets, that are split in different OSM "ways"

Is there a way to get all the nodes of a same street having more than "one way" to get all the coordinates across that street ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try to query the street name and get all ways with the same name. Then you could take all individual nodes and you should have what you want. I know Nominatim does that mapping but I'm not familiar with the api's you mentioned.

Another (maybe more cumbersome) method is to look at the nodes of your way and see in what ways they are involved. If you take your example, the node 42426060 is part of both ways you're looking for. If you could query the ways for that node and match them (according to name), you could merge them yourself.

Comment: I thought about getting all ways with the same name, but: 1) not always the name of the street is the same (I've seen cases of "Rue de la Vie" and "Rue la Vie", for example)   2) not all the "ways" are connected with the same node, so it would be a tough mathematical task to know which way edge has to connect with the other

Comment: I think you are never going to solve the problems like your first example (Rue de la Vie). If the names are different and some other information as well, who's to say that they should be merged in the first place? You could write some complex match function that allows one or two letters to be different but that's a lot of work... As for your other example, do you want to merge streets that in reality aren't connected (but have the same name)? If your query is limited, then you might try to correct some of the mistakes in OSM itself (those name corrections will be welcomed)